# Do the Gorkha people from Nepal have their ancestral origin in the people who were once the part of Gorakhnath's army?

Tags: history

I heard somewhere that some king of Nepal was forcefully converting Hindu Sadhus to Buddhism.
When Gorakhnath heard about it, he built an army from clay then made that army alive and defeated the king.
Also he made his disciple named Vasanta who always had a dream of becoming a king as the king of Nepal.
And the people of that army made from clay were called Gorakhas as they were Gorakhnath's army.
Is it true? If yes then I would like to know more about it?

Comment: [History Stack Exchange](https://history.stackexchange.com/) would be suitable for history questions.